# Best Way in Spring or Thymeleaf to Handle Internationalization of Database Values

Tags: database, spring-mvc, internationalization, resourcebundle, thymeleaf

I am using Spring with Thymeleaf and I have set up internationalization with resource bundles.  That works fine.  However, I am wondering what is the best way to handle system values in the database for things like, drop down list, multi-selects, etc.  Is it best to add the international values to the DB and change the query to select by locale or is there a better way?  Personally, I would like to reuse the resource bundles I already have, since that would keep all the internationalization to one location.